# Where is the "defaults" executable on OS X stored?

Tags: macos, terminal, file-location

I need to run the "defaults" command from my code, but I can't just use "defaults write blah blah", instead I need the use the path for the defaults executable and then add the arguments later. However, I have been unable to locate the defaults executable.

Where is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the command

```
defaults
```

works from a terminal, you can execute

```
which defaults
```

in that terminal to locate the associated executable.

See:

- [UNIX man pages : which ()](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which)
- [which OSX Man Page | SS64.com](http://ss64.com/mac/which.html)

Comment: Nifty. Thanks a lot. I thought there must be a command like that.